# Will the water level change due to releasing a ironic ball from a floating ice cube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, buoyancy

A piece of ice is floating in a glass of water. There is a small ironic ball inside the piece of ice.
[image: Visualization of the question]

If the ice completely melts, the ball will be released into the water. Then will there be any change in the water level?